# on click, open a new window pass through some state with router link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi there I am trying to pass some state between two components.

This is how my code is looking right now , and its working

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'adminCashFlow',  params: { data: this.document })
```

I want this adminCashFlow component to open in a new window, thanks.

Comment: New window or new tab ?

Comment: I want to open on a new window, this component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
url=''// your route path
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```